# nodejs angularjs render html file and not a resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Hi I have few problems. 
I have a angular service that use $resource, and I use it to make all my AJAX requests.

```
angular.module("UserRegisterService", [ "ngResource" ] )
.factory("userService", function($resource, $location) {

var URL_API = "http://localhost/";
    { 

        "sendLoginUser" : { method: "POST", url: URL_API + "login" }

    });

return {

    sendLoginUser: function(user) {
        return serviceRest.sendLoginUser(user, function(){
            alert("LOGIN - Succés");
        }, function(response){
            alert("Error :"+ response.status +" "+ response.data);
        });

    }
```

So it calls my route :

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {session: true}), function(req, res){

    res.redirect('/planning');

});
```

And then this :

```
router.get('/planning', function(req,res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated())
    next();
else
    res.send(401);

},function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/views/planning.html'));
});
```

But the `res.sendFile` returns a Resource to my client with code in a array :
[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ4oW.jpg)

How can I sendFile to display the index.html and not returning it as a Resource ?